# Setup Zendframework 2 and twitter bootstrap using Composer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2, dependency-management, composer-php

I am currently using composer dependency manager for zendframework 2 along with twitter bootstrap , I able to successfully manage zendframework 2 but I am not able manage twitter bootstrap via composer .

The problem is composer downloads twitter bootstrap library to vender directory . This is not feasible I need composer to download twitter bootstrap to public folder and zendframework to vender folder . how to achieve this

Below is the current composer.json file that I am using .

```
    {
        "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
        "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
        "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "zf2"
        ],
        "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
            "twitter/bootstrap":"2.*"
        },
        "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "public/bootstrap/": ["twitter/bootstrap", "twitter/bootstrap"],
            "vender/zendframework" : ["zendframework/zendframework" ,"zendframework/zendframework"]
            }
         }  
}
```

I am new to composer Please kindly suggest correct way of specifying path for each required library in composer.json file ,

The above code is throwing error as invalid format .

Comment: If this is really your file, check line of `vendor/zendframework`. Downvoting someone that's trying to help you instead of making your problem more clear to him, ain't the best way to get more help of said person...

Comment: @Sam Yes it is mine only , I got this file when I am installed skeleton application of zendframework . When I remove the extra parameter in the file it works but dumps twitter bootstrap to vender directiory . I need that to go into custom directory of my own If this is not possible for sure why dont that person say its not possible . I downvoted because because he has not given the answer by understanding the problem , He also would have posted a comment for clarification like the way you have done , I believe thats the perfect way .

Comment: @Sam I am really sorry if you have felt bad for down voting there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying every approach I posted the issue on github composer repository , Below is the link

[Setup Zendframework 2 and twitter bootstrap using Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1613)

[@Seldaek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6512/seldaek) have closed the issue , by responding to that issue  , As per his comments

Composer is not made to download front end dependencies at the moment. His suggested solution to manage twitter bootstrap is to use [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) a Browser package manager from twitter .

Bower is also a good tool to use for managing all sort of front end packages and keep it up to date in your project, . I tried and I was successful in managing twitter boot strap and other JS libraries .

I just decided to post this to help others who are also searching solution for the same problem ,

This posting definitely helps others to decide on process to follow for managing front end libraries in projects .

Comment: Thanks to @Seldaek for helping me by responding to my issue at github

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom installer to install to a different path

http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md

Comment: hmmm -1 for what reason? :)

Comment: Is there a way where I can find a sample custom installer for twitter bootstrap

Comment: I am now really downvoting it , because I am not the package author here I want twitter bootstrap to use a Custom package

Comment: My problem is different then what you have specified

Comment: You can do it that way, you could also created a symlink and just let the files be stored inside the vendor folder if you can't figure out how to install to a custom path.

Comment: Hmmm I knew that , which was specified in the Composer Git hub issues by some user .But I couldn’t use like that I want to automate it like the way zend framework 2 gets updated , I am really sorry if you are hurt with my down vote .